# Does watir-webdriver have a "wildcard tag"?

Tags: ruby, wildcard, watir, watir-webdriver

You know how you can search a page's source like this:

```
browser.div(:text => /foo/)
```

How can you do something like this:

```
browser.wildcard(:text => /foo/)
```

I'm looking for this functionality because I visit page 1 which has

```
<tag1>foo</tag1>
```

but page 2 has

```
<tag2>foo</tag2>
```

and it is a certainty that foo occurs nowhere else in the page for both pages.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what are `<tag1>` and `<tag2>`?

Comment: `<td>` and `<span>`, but I found a work around that doesn't require `element`.

Comment: @orde, out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: I was just wondering what your use case was.

Answer (score 3):

Element will find any element that matches regardless of tag name:

`browser.element(text: /foo/)`

Justin makes a great point in the comments. Pairing `#element` with a regex value will result in returning the `html` element.

If you want the last tag that references it (note that this is probably a prohibitively non-performant option):

`browser.element(text: /foo/, index: -1)`

If there aren't any issues with nested spans, this would be a slightly faster option:

`b.element(text: /foo/, tag_name: /span|td/)`

In general, it is much much better to avoid using regular expression matchers when you don't *have to use them.

Comment: I think you have to be careful with this. If "foo" is on the page, it will always return the `html` element, which is the first element that contains the text. If the tag text is known to be exactly "foo", `browser.element(text: 'foo')` will be safer.

Answer (score 0):

How about xpath?

```
browser.element(xpath: "//tag1[contains(text(),'foo')]")
```

If you have only one tag1 on the page you can even:

```
browser.element(xpath: "//tag1")
```